# lateinit property presenter has not been initialized through Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I faced with the following problem while adding Dagger to my project. I read several articles, where was written that all lines similar to this:

```
private val presenter = FavoritesPresenter()
```

should be replaced with `DI`. Please, correct me if I am wrong and this is wrong way.
I created a special component for it:

```
AppComponent:

@Component(
        modules = [FavoritesModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent: AndroidInjector<TraktTvApp>{

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: TraktTvApp): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

}
```

and Module:

```
FavoritesModule

@Module
abstract class FavoritesModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun favoritesPresenter(favoritesPresenter: FavoritesPresenter): FavoritesContract.FavoritesPresenter

}
```

By this way I am trying to create a new instance of Presenter.Probably I don't understand the necessity of such parameters, but when I tried to change the signature in the following way:

```
abstract fun favoritesPresenter(): FavoritesPresenter
```

my app crashed during compilation.

And now my Fragment, where I had a line

```
private val presenter = FavoritesPresenter()
```

looks like:

```
class FavoritesFragment : Fragment(), FavoritesContract.FavoritesView, MoviesAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter:FavoritesPresenter

*other code*
}
```

But when I run my app I have the following exception:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   presenter has not been initialized
>           at com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment.onViewCreated(FavoritesFragment.kt:41)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

So, what I did wrong and how can I solve this problem correctly?

**UPD**

And here's a code of my presenter:

```
class FavoritesPresenter @Inject constructor() : BasePresenter<FavoritesContract.FavoritesView>(), FavoritesContract.FavoritesPresenter, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector:DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
}
```

**UPD 2**

I added the following methods to AppComponent:

```
override fun inject(application: TraktTvApp)

fun inject(fragment: Fragment)
```

But it also didn't help

Comment: did you override `onAttach` to 'register' your fragment?

Comment: @Blackbelt, yes

Comment: `HasSupportFragmentInjector` should be implemented by the `Activity` hosting the `fragment` iirc

Comment: @Blackbelt I moved it to MainActivity, which places needle fragment, but I still get the same exception

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii you've added the `inject` method to the component, but have you used it in the `FavoritesFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector:DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
}
```

This code should be in your fragment not in presenter because Presenter is a dependency for a Fragment.

Comment: Still the same: presenter isn't initialized